# Wedding Invitation Sentence Structure

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Would love some help with this. I'm creating a wedding invitation card and am confused on how it should be written. The invitation is for my dinner reception. I'm the grandson of Mr. & Mrs. Grandparents and son of Mr. & Mrs. Parents.

"On behalf of the late Mr. & Mrs. Grandparents, Mr. & Mrs. Parents request the honour of your presence to the dinner reception of their beloved **grandson**"

should the text in bold be "grandson" or "son"?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to express? That you are your deceased grandparent's grandson or that you are your parent's son? You need to make your *intention* clearer in the question.

Comment: Without meaning to be flippant, I don't see how the parents can invite guests _on behalf of_ deceased grandparents. If you particularly wish to honour them, could you say "...their beloved son, grandson of the late Mr & Mrs Grandparents"?

Comment: To write such an invitation would not be something that would occur in American English language culture.  That is, make a reference to late grandparents.

Comment: You should accept the answer. When you do, a green checkmark will appear, you'll be rewarded with 2 reputation points and the user will earn 15 rep.

Comment: To accept an answer click on the tick (BrEng) or checkmark (AmEng).

Answer (score 2):

I think this sentence is the proper way to write the invitation:

> "Mr. & Mrs. Parents request the honor of your presence to the dinner
>   reception of their beloved *son*, '**YourName**', *grandson* of late
>   Mr. & Mrs. Grandparents".

Comment: Don't forget to give a time and date. Also, an RSVP date in good time before the wedding so you know how many people are coming. And you could say "wedding reception" instead of "dinner reception".

Comment: Whatever you do about the son/grandson issue, it's presence *at*, not presence *to*.

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Comment: **at** the dinner reception. BTW, I think that *dinner reception* is fine, since it sounds welcoming, and helps the guest visualize what’s in store for them.